# Laravel eager loading not returning data

Tags: foreach, laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading

**Scenario**:

An alert belongs to 1 user and 1 location, both referenced, respectively, by foreign keys in the `alert` table - user_id and location_id. The user_id will be the same for each request, but the location_id most definitely differs.

I want to display all alerts relating to that one user, I have successfully achieved this but without the use of eager loading.

my getIndex function so far:

```
public function getIndex()
    {   
        $alert = User::with('alerts.location')
                            ->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.index', 
                                             array('alert' => $alert));
    }
```

Printing the MYSQL query seems logically correct however, I am struggling to show the 'locations' part of the query.

My foreach loop is:

```
@foreach($alert->locations as $alert)
    <td>{{ $alert->location->address_1}}</td>
@endforeach
```

However, it returns the error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By accessing the data using this forloop, I was able to resolve the problem `@foreach($alert->alerts as $alert)`.